# Kia problems rpms/speedometer

Tags: kia, speedometer

I have a Kia - occasionally it will rev up to 3rpm at about 40mph but stop once I get past that. I took it to a trusted mechanic who found nothing wrong - filter, fluids, etc - this morning, the speedometer jumped while I was driving. Each time the engine seems to drag but then goes back to normal and all is good...I drive an hour to work each morning and an hour to my parents house once a week, so I’m on the road a lot. What can I do if it’s not presenting itself with the mechanic?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is this a manual or automatic transmission? Also, what is the year/model/engine of your Kia?

Comment: Automatic transmission 2012